# How to split by Replacement Character "" in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have this character ``, or see screenshot below. Its the "replacement character" in Ruby.

[image]

I'm using an external API that does parsing, and unfortunately returns this character instead of `-` for un-ordered list points.

I would like to split by this character in what is returned, but I've been unsuccessful with below.

```
text.split(//)
```

How can I split by this character?

Comment: Can you read it in and find its unicode value?

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/140350). You have an encoding problem—for example, you're trying to read or display data as one encoding when it actually has another encoding—but instead of solving that you've asked how to solve a different problem, which is splitting a string based on the result of that encoding problem. Your question should ask how (and provide details necessary) to solve the former, not the latter.

Comment: I agree with both the comments above determine the unicode value and split on that or determine the appropriate encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These will match any non `ASCII` character:

`[^\x00-\x7F]` or `[^[:ascii:]]`.

As noted by @engineersmnky this may not be the most ideal solution if the data you are parsing could contain more unrecognized characters.

Use this regex if you want to split **only** the `` character:

```
[\uF0B7]
```

Comment: This is a decent solution, although I think posix based `[^[:ascii:]]` reads better, but only use this if you can guarantee that the API does not return any other non ascii characters. Which limits you to pretty much just English (and even then borrowed words like "café" might be split apart).

Comment: @engineersmnky I have updated the answer to include your recommendation, and have also provided a regex that will only split the `` character.